# Webpack Encore select2 not working with not a function import error

Tags: symfony, jquery-select2, webpack-encore

Using **Symfony 4** and **Webpack Encore**, I can't get **Select2** to work.

I'm using `select2@4.0.3` and importing it this way in `app.js`:

```
import $  from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'select2';
```

I also tried to use

```
Encore.autoProvidejQuery()
```

in `webpack.config.js`, then taking care of commenting the

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

line in `app.js` so that jquery is not imported twice.

I tried everything I could find in other answsers like:

```
import select2 form 'select2';

$(() => {
  $('.select2-enable').select2();
});
```

or

```
select2($);
```

Almost all my attempts result in the same error:

> TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

**EDIT:**

Working now. Everytime I made a change in `app.js` (and rebuilt) I used the firefox devtool console to check if it was working but I always got the

> not a function

error even though the problem was solved and select2 was working.

Is this because I'm using Webpack that the browser console doesn't recognize the `select2()` function anymore?

Comment: Did you rebuild, after this code? If yes, could you share your html codes?

Comment: first install it using `yarn add select2` then use it with `require` instead of `import` like : `require('select2')` at your `app.js` file

Comment: @Trix : Thanks for your comment. Got it working (see my edit), I was mislead by strange browser console's behavior (it doesn't work in console). It works the same using require or import.

Comment: @Mert, Thank for your comment. Yes I rebuilt after every change. About my html code: I'm calling select2() in a vue.js component method.

Answer (score 1):

First install it using `yarn`:

```
yarn add select2
```

Then use it with `require` instead of `import`:

```
require('select2')
```

at your `app.js` file.

> It works the same using require or import.

Babel converts import and export declaration to CommonJS (require) which lets you load modules dynamically.

So, despite of them looking the same, try to always use require.